# WPF - repeat elements from list

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I try to do a WPF Application. The Application should look like the followings.

Title - top left
Button "New Entry" - top right
after this, there is a table or something like this.
with three columns per entry. On the first column the name, second the text and on the third column a button.

The name, text and the button should be shown and repeated for every element in my generic list.

How can I do this? Is there a repeater control like in WebForms? Can I use the ListView? If so, how can I configure it?

Any help would be appreciated.

thanks!

Comment: could you reformat your question? It's difficult to understand what you want to ask. If you could elaborate functionality you intend to achieve, that will ease in explaining solution. WPF provides template programming, it might help you.

Comment: I have a List of Server. I'd like to make a user interface thats shows the list. The Object Server contains Name and Text.

Comment: The GUI should look like this  http://i.imgur.com/ghXoC.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should do is create a dataGrid in xaml, bind the columns to your fields, and then set the itemssource to that data grid:

```
<DataGrid 
    x:Name="ItemsDataGrid"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    HeadersVisibility="Column"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=YourDataCollection, Mode=OneWay}"
    SelectionChanged="IfYouWantToDoSomethingHereHandler"
    >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn 
            Header="Name"
            Binding="{Binding Path=NameFromYourDataObject, Mode=TwoWay}" 
            Width="Auto"
            />
        <DataGridTextColumn 
            Header="DescriptionText"
            Binding="{Binding Path=DescriptionFromYourDataObject, Mode=TwoWay}" 
            Width="Auto"
            />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn 
            Header="ButtonColumn"
            CellTemplate="{StaticResource ButtonTemplate}"
            Width="Auto"
             />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Where ButtonTemplate is a DataTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate
    x:Key="ButtonTemplate"
    >
        <Button
            -- bind a command here of what the pressing of the button should look like
            />
</DataTemplate>
```

All you have to do from here on is create the DataObject, create a List or ObservableCollection("YourDataCollection"), fill it up with this data, and then set the ItemsSource of ItemsDataGrid.

That should be it.. 
 HTH, Daniel

Comment: and also add Header template for second column to have 'New Entry' button with command to add new entry in collection thats bound with above datagrid.